# Displaying sheet/sub total in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a requirement to display sheet total at the end of every page in a SSRS report. Sheet total is the sum of all transactions being displayed on that page only, not the running total. There is no grouping of transactions i.e. I'm not referring to sub total per group.
Is it this feasible?

Thanks,
Sumit

Comment: Yes it is possible, But you have to fix the how many rows you want to show on each page

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above subtotal, first you need to break your page in fixed number of rows and for this you need to add a parent group in your tablix. Then go to expression of the that Group property and write the following

```
=Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/50)
```

before pressing ok goto Sorting property of your group and delete the expression there.

Now you fixed your page to 50 Rows per page, just add a Subtotal for each group and you will get what you want.

Comment: The format of first and subsequent(overflow pages) is different for my report.
In other works the number of records on the page will be different on the first page. I guess this approach wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: That's what I am saying that you need to fix the number of rows on each page using the above expression and then calculate the subtotal.

Comment: If I fix the number of rows based on first page, then there will be white space on overflow pages. This is not acceptable. My first page can accomodate only 17 rows because of the footer the following pages can show 42 rows . So, should I use 2 tablix and force a page break? I mean restrict data in 1st tablix to 17, force page break, push rest of the data into the second tablix. The expression for 1st tablix grouping would be =Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/17) and the second tablix would be =Int((RowNumber(Nothing)-1)/42).